# How to generate dummies for all holidays (date format = %Y/"%M/%d" ) for all years?

Tags: r, date

I am trying to generate a dummy variable Ht that takes on the value 1 if that date `(format = "%Y/%M/%D")` is a national holiday. My dataset goes from `1979-07-03` to `2018-12-31`, therefore I need to for example generate a dummy that = 1 on Jan 1st, December 31st...etc for all the years. (Same dates every single year across all years).

I can't seem to find codes to get this dummy. Can someone please help?

```
data$Ht <- ifelse(data$Date > as.Date("12/01/2007", format = "%M/%d/%Y") &
                     dat$date < as.Date("06/01/2009", format = "%M/%d/%Y"), 0, 1)
```

Comment: I think the `format = "%m/%d/%Y"` and you don't need `ifelse` `as.integer(data$Date > as.Date("12/01/2007", format = "%m/%d/%Y") & dat$date < as.Date("06/01/2009", format = "%m/%d/%Y"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can develop a sequence of dates and a sequence of dates for holidays.

```
date_seq = seq(from = as.Date('1979-07-03'), to = as.Date('2018-12-31'), by= '1 day')
new_years_day = seq(from = as.Date('1980-01-01'), to = as.Date('2018-01-01'), by = '1 year' )
christmas_day = seq(from = as.Date('1980-12-25'), to = as.Date('2018-12-25'), by = '1 year' )

dummy = as.integer(date_seq %in% new_years_day | date_seq %in% christmas_day)
```